# groovydoc for local package links

Tags: groovy, groovydoc

In my groovy file, I have a groovydoc link that looks like:

```
/**
 * This links to {@link MyClassInSamePackage}
 */
def myMethod() {

}
```

Because the class of `myMethod` is the same package as `MyClassInSamePackage`, this should work, but it doesn't generate a link in the docs, rather it surrounds it in `<code>` tags. I have recently opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5957, but according to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3745, it looks like this issue should be fixed (I'm using groovy 2.0.5).

Can anyone confirm (or refute) whether or not links in the same package work properly in groovydoc if the full package name is not used?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Grails 2.2 with Groovy 2.0.5 and I see the same behaviour, except that it seems that GroovyDoc's function of creating `@link` tags, as well as `@see` tags is unpredictable and sometimes its working - sometimes it's not.

It could also be a bug within my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 Ultimate - 30 Days Trial Version), but if you see this behaviour too, maybe it's some bug within `Groovydoc`?

Which IDE do you use?